# Flash/SWF file + fixed positioning

Tags: css, flash, positioning

I seem to have found a problem with SWF files that are embedded in a fixed  at the top of the page. When a swf file is embedded, the  doesn't stick to the top of the page - here's an example code:

```
<div id="headerOuter" style="z-index: 10001; position: relative; visibility: visible; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 100%; height: 80px; overflow: hidden; background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0); "><div id="twrap" style="z-index: 10001; position: fixed; visibility: visible; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 100%; height: 80px; overflow: hidden; background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0); "><div id="skyTop" style="width: 900px; height: 80px; position: relative; cursor: pointer; visibility: visible; margin-left: -450px; margin-right: 0px; background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0); left: 50%; "><object classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000" width="900" height="80"><param name="movie" value="http://new.skinected.com-appnexus-akiai4avqn7qtsn2aowq.s3.amazonaws.com/80d6b512a3ceb9e9ad4e4f6c25c843be.swf"><param name="quality" value="high"><param name="FlashVars" value="clickTAG=http%3A%2F%2F5150.com&amp;clickTag=http%3A%2F%2F5150.com"><param name="flashvars" value="clickTAG=http%3A%2F%2F5150.com&amp;clickTag=http%3A%2F%2F5150.com"><embed src="http://new.skinected.com-appnexus-akiai4avqn7qtsn2aowq.s3.amazonaws.com/80d6b512a3ceb9e9ad4e4f6c25c843be.swf" quality="high" width="900" height="80" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" flashvars="clickTAG=http%3A%2F%2F5150.com&amp;clickTag=http%3A%2F%2F5150.com"></object></div></div></div>
```

Enter that into an HTML page and it doesn't work, even though the outer div wrappers are setup correctly.

If I put an image or other basic html code into the #headerOuter div all is well, but the object/embed doesn't work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Use `position:fixed` or `position:absolute` instead of using `position:relative` in the `style` of the `<div id="headerOuter">`

----------------------------------------------------- **More Description:** ----------------------------------------------------

> ***Static Positioning*** OR [ position:static ]
>
> HTML elements are positioned static by default. A static positioned element is always positioned according to the normal flow of the page.
>
> ***Relative Positioning*** OR [ position:relative ]
>
> A relative positioned element is positioned relative to its normal position.
>
> ***Fixed Positioning*** OR [ position:fixed ]
>
> An element with fixed position is positioned relative to the browser window.
>
> ***Absolute Positioning*** OR [ position:absolute ]
>
> An absolute position element is positioned relative to the first parent element that has a position other than static.

A reference URL : [CSS Positioning](http://www.w3schools.com/Css/css_positioning.asp)